# How to add custom js after validation result

Tags: asp.net

I need to call my own javascript function after OnServerValidate returns positive result.

```
<asp:CustomValidator Display="Dynamic" OnServerValidate="DBValidate">
```

I cannot use jQuery or any other external javascript libraries.

Answer (score 1):

On server write:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "MyScript", "alert('MyScript');", true);
```

This script will be executed immediately when server will return the response to client.